# Firebase deploy error: "No i18n config on project."

Tags: internationalization, firebase-hosting, transloco

To deploy my Angular project I ran `ng build --configuration production` and then `firebase deploy --only hosting`. It says:

```
Thank you for trying our early preview of Angular support on Firebase Hosting.
During the preview, support is best-effort and breaking changes can be expected. Proceed with caution.

Documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/frameworks/angular
File a bug: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/new?template=bug_report.md
Submit a feature request: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/new?template=feature_request.md

We'd love to learn from you. Express your interest in helping us shape the future of Firebase Hosting: https://goo.gle/41enW5X

Error: No i18n config on project.
```

I have Transloco 5.0.7 installed. Reading how to [Configure internationalization (i18n) rewrites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/i18n-rewrites), it appears that Firebase Hosting is looking for this:

```js
  "i18n": {
      "root": "/localized-files"
    },
```

in `firebase.json`. It expects to see `localized-files` in the `public` directory:

```
public/localized-files/
```

My Angular app doesn't have this directory structure. I have:

```
src/app/assets/i18n/
```

I tried

```js
  "i18n": {
      "root": "src/app/assets/i18n/"
    },
```

```js
  "i18n": {
      "root": "app/assets/i18n/"
    },
```

```js
  "i18n": {
      "root": "/assets/i18n/"
    },
```

and

```js
  "i18n": {
      "root": "assets/i18n/"
    },
```

These all throw similar errors:

```
hosting: Couldn't find specified i18n root directory /assets/i18n in public directory .
```

Is there another config line in `firebase.json` that tells Firebase Hosting that Angular puts `index.html` in an `app` directory, not a `public` directory?

Answer (score 1):

I think that there is no need to replace `source` by `public`.

I’ve prepared an example repository at [ng-test-i18n](https://github.com/9kubczas4/ng-test-i18n).
This repository is targeting Angular v16 with `@ngneat/transloco` v6.0.0.

I guess the problem was the wrong value for the `i18n root`.
I've used `src/assets/i18n` and for such configuration deployment to Firebase worked without any issues or warnings.

Below is entire `firebase.json` file:

```json
{
  "hosting": {
    "source": ".",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "frameworksBackend": {
      "region": "us-central1"
    },
    "i18n": {
      "root": "src/assets/i18n"
    }
  }
}
```

Note: deployment to Firebase was done using `firebase-tools` v12.5.2

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

The two doc pages I read were:

[Configure Hosting behavior](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config)

[Configure internationalization (i18n) rewrites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/i18n-rewrites)

If you have Transloco installed and running you don't need to touch anything there. Find the folder with your Transloco files. My folder is in

```
src/app/assets/i18n
```

Open `firebase.json` and make two changes. First, put in the path to your `i18n` folder:

```js
"i18n": {
    "root": "/assets/i18n"
},
```

Next, remove the line `"source": ".",` and replace it with the path to the folder that contains your `index.html` file. Firebase calls this your `public` directory.

```
"public": "dist/en-US",
```

Watch out for a few things. First, don't use `source`. This no longer works. You must use `public`.

Second, `public` points to the directory that contains your `index.html` file. An Angular app has two `index.html` files! In fact, Angular apps have two of every file: `src` and `dist`. `dist` is where your compiled, ready to deploy files are. Don't point your `public` folder to `src`.

Third, I have no idea why Angular compiles my app into `dist/en-US` instead of `dist`. I think this is a bug in Transloco.

Here's my entire `firebase.json` file:

```js
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/en-US",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "i18n": {
      "root": "/assets/i18n"
    },
    "frameworksBackend": {
      "region": "us-central1"
    }
  },
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    },
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080
    },
    "hosting": {
      "port": 5000
    },
    "storage": {
      "port": 9199
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "singleProjectMode": true
  },
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ],
      "predeploy": [
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```